# Get File Video Info in C# or Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, file, video

I´m developing a Video Upload and View Solution over HTML5 and I would like to know if there is a way to get the video info in the client in javascript. I think that this is not posible.
In other hands I suppose it may be posible in C#.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: You can read the metadata: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46976783/2550529

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I didn´t get any information at the client, no more than the extension, so you don´t know nothing about the codecs, resolution and others in the client. You have to send it to the server and process it and for me the best option is FFMPEG.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the video information in C# then it is also possible to get it in `Javascript` too, because you just have to expose a service to get the video info in `javascript` using MVC WebApi, Asp.net, WCF or Asp.net MVC.

Comment: You are right, but think in a video of more than 100 mg. It would be very slow to send the video to the server...